# Sort values from smallest to largest among all string values Execution started and Execution ended

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

```
<!--00:00:13:23 - Execution started - 01042141053 - B Side
00:02:59:10 - VAR 10.2 = 'W2300900009'
00:02:50:78 - VAR 8.2 = 'W2300900007' 
00:02:42:51 - VAR 6.2 = 'W2300900005' 
00:03:45:18 - Execution ended'
System in Power Counter = 49035:41:56 
'00:04:01:29 - Execution started - 01042141053 
'00:04:40:28 - VAR 4.2 = 'W2300900023'
'00:04:36:36 - VAR 3.2 = 'W2300900022'
'00:04:32:34 - VAR 2.2 = 'W2300900021'
'00:05:50:62 - Execution ended'
```

This is part of workstation log and I need to sort it by S/N (W2300900009)(highlighted values) from "execute started" to "Execute ended".Would you know how to use the pandas library(Python)? Shortly how to reorder values from smallest to largest between two string values..

The result should look like this:

```
'00:00:13:23 - Execution started - 01042141053 - B Side'
'00:02:42:51 - VAR 6.2 = 'W2300900005'
'00:02:50:78 - VAR 8.2 = 'W2300900007'
'00:02:59:10 - VAR 10.2 = 'W2300900009'
'00:03:45:18 - Execution ended'
System in Power Counter = 49035:41:56
'00:04:01:29 - Execution started - 01042141053
'00:04:32:34 - VAR 2.2 = 'W2300900021'   
'00:04:36:36 - VAR 3.2 = 'W2300900022'
'00:04:40:28 - VAR 4.2 = 'W2300900023'
'00:05:50:62 - Execution ended'-->
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is S/N? What would the sorted result look like? Could you please [edit] the log by adding newlines, so we can see how the log is split into distinct elements?

Comment: How do you propose to **sort** a single string? My guess is that there should be line breaks before each date. You don't need *pandas* for this. Are the serial numbers always exactly 10 digits?

Comment: Why did the middle line get deleted?

Comment: The middle line is not important for MES interface. Every row out of start and end execute is not important.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for wanting to use *pandas*? Why over-complicate something that's really quite trivial

Answer (score 0):

One option, is to use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = (pd.read_csv("logfile.txt", sep="/", header=None)
          .loc[lambda x: ~x[0].str.contains("Counter")]
          .reset_index(drop=True)
     )
​
m = df[0].str.contains("Execution ended")
​
df["S/N"] = np.where(m, "End", df[0].str.extract("VAR \d+\.\d = 'W(\d+)'", expand=False))
df["flag"] = m.cumsum().shift().fillna(0)
​
out = (df.groupby(df.pop("flag"), group_keys=False)
          .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by= "S/N", na_position="first"))
          .fillna({"S/N": "Start"}).rename({0:"logfile"}, axis=1))
​
```

As you can see from the row's indexes (*see below*), the sort is effective.

Output :

```
print(out)
                                                      logfile         S/N
0  <!--00:00:13:23 - Execution started - 01042141053 - B Side       Start
3                      00:02:42:51 - VAR 6.2 = 'W2300900005'   2300900005
2                      00:02:50:78 - VAR 8.2 = 'W2300900007'   2300900007
1                      00:02:59:10 - VAR 10.2 = 'W2300900009'  2300900009
4                              00:03:45:18 - Execution ended'         End
5             '00:04:01:29 - Execution started - 01042141053        Start
8                      '00:04:32:34 - VAR 2.2 = 'W2300900021'  2300900021
7                      '00:04:36:36 - VAR 3.2 = 'W2300900022'  2300900022
6                      '00:04:40:28 - VAR 4.2 = 'W2300900023'  2300900023
9                             '00:05:50:62 - Execution ended'         End
```

Comment: I think OP has no good reason to flag pandas. Maybe she thinks that's the most appropriate tool for this task. Well, it isn't. The code in this answer is perfectly correct for what it does although it doesn't produce the required output and is incredibly slow

Comment: I did that on purpose (keeping 2 columns) so we can see the difference in the output. My answer is to give a general logic to OP and whether it's a good/fast approach to use, that's up to them. Thanks Pingu ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the lines looking for 'Execution started' and 'Execution ended'.

All lines need to be in the output list. Lines between 'Execution started' and 'Execution ended' need to be in  the output list but sorted on the serial number which, in the following code, is assumed to be the last token in a line and is surrounded by single-quotes

In which case:

```
s = """'00:00:13:23 - Execution started - 01042141053 - B Side'
'00:02:59:10 - VAR 10.2 = 'W2300900009'
'00:02:50:78 - VAR 8.2 = 'W2300900007' 
'00:02:42:51 - VAR 6.2 = 'W2300900005' 
'00:03:45:18 - Execution ended'
System in Power Counter = 49035:41:56 
'00:04:01:29 - Execution started - 01042141053 
'00:04:40:28 - VAR 4.2 = 'W2300900023'
'00:04:36:36 - VAR 3.2 = 'W2300900022'
'00:04:32:34 - VAR 2.2 = 'W2300900021'
'00:05:50:62 - Execution ended'"""

output = []
started = False

for line in s.splitlines():
    if started:
        if 'Execution ended' in line:
            output += sorted(slist, key=lambda x: x.split()[-1][1:-1])
            output.append(line)
            started = False
        else:
            slist.append(line)
    else:
        if 'Execution started' in line:
            started = True
            slist = []
        output.append(line)

print(*output, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
'00:00:13:23 - Execution started - 01042141053 - B Side'
'00:02:42:51 - VAR 6.2 = 'W2300900005' 
'00:02:50:78 - VAR 8.2 = 'W2300900007' 
'00:02:59:10 - VAR 10.2 = 'W2300900009'
'00:03:45:18 - Execution ended'
System in Power Counter = 49035:41:56 
'00:04:01:29 - Execution started - 01042141053 
'00:04:32:34 - VAR 2.2 = 'W2300900021'
'00:04:36:36 - VAR 3.2 = 'W2300900022'
'00:04:40:28 - VAR 4.2 = 'W2300900023'
'00:05:50:62 - Execution ended'
```

Comment: I'd do `if not started:` and swap the blocks. I always find it easier to read first what happens first and to read later what happens later.